# Javascript Multidimension array remove

Tags: javascript

I have a array like this:

```
array = [
    ['ID','Name','Gender']
    ['1', 'John', 'Male']
    ['2', 'Mark', 'Male']
   ]
```

I want to delete the first array, which is `['ID','Name','Gender']` But how can I delete this array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shift()` to remove the first array

```js
let array = [
  ['ID', 'Name', 'Gender'],
  ['1', 'John', 'Male'],
  ['2', 'Mark', 'Male'],
]

array.shift();

console.log(array);
```

Doc: [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: Thanks It worked.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
let array = [
  ['ID', 'Name', 'Gender'],
  ['1', 'John', 'Male'],
  ['2', 'Mark', 'Male'],
]

array.splice(0, 1);

console.log(array);
```